# Use Curl PHP to upload image from external URL

Tags: php, curl

I'm working with an API that expects the following Curl to upload an image:

```
curl https://api.example.com/vehicles/7e59591f-c5a3-974e-e452-2951040ae4ee/images \
 -X POST \
 -H "X-AS24-Version: 1.1" \
 -H "Accept-Language: en-GB" \
 -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer e7c00b24-9f5f-4909-88de-38f8d7ca08bf" \
 -F "file=@foto.jpg"
```

Now I want my PHP script to upload an image from an external URL to upload the image. But I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
$url = 'https://api.example.com/vehicles/' . $vehicleId . '/images';

$args['file'] ='@http://www.example.com/foto.jpg'; 
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-AS24-Version: 1.1',
    'Accept-Language: en-GB',
    'Content-type: multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

I got no response at all.
What am I doing wrong or is it even possible to upload from an URL?

Comment: If you command is working fine, and issue in PHP code, then you can convert curl command to PHP code by this, `https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/`

Comment: Thank you @harishsharma